# Sorting nested elements with elementtree

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, elementtree

I am attempting to sort elements that are heavily nested within an XML file using XML attributes with *elementree*. The structure of XML elements i need to read is this:

```xml
<ChargeItem>
   <!-- some other data-->  
   <SupplementaryOffer OfferID=SomeIdNumber>
       <!-- more data-->  
   </SupplementaryOffer>
</ChargeItem>
```

My code should do next:

1. Parse XML file, get `SupplementaryOffer` tag
2. read `OfferID` attribute.
3. Add an new attribute `OrderID` based on lookup list.
4. Sort each `SuplementaryOffer` based on `OrderID` within `ChargeItem`.

What I now need to do now is: *sort each `SupplementaryOffer`* (4) with
 this code:

```py
for c in tree.iter("ChargeItem"):
    c[:] = sorted(c, key=lambda child: (child.tag,child.get('OrderId')))
```

Is what I using to try and sort, however as far as I can tell, this is not functioning whatsoever.

Below is the cut-down existing XML, with the 'OrderId' attribute already added:

```xml
<BATCH >
    <BILL>
        <Somebillinfo>0</Somebillinfo>
        <INVtype>2</INVtype>
        <PageOne>
            <Stuff></Stuff>
        </PageOne>
        <Page2>
            <ServiceAddressCharges>
                <ServiceAddress>
                    <ServiceAddress1>221B Baker Street</ServiceAddress1>
                </ServiceAddress>
                <ProductsSection>
                    <BrilliantProducts id="20033" DisplayMethod="0">Snack services
                        <ChargeItemList>
                            <ServiceNo>0123456478</ServiceNo>
                            <PrimaryOffer OfferId="80000000">Blueberry Icecream</PrimaryOffer>
                            <ParentBundle SortKey="NO_BUNDLE" ParentBundleId="0" ConnectReason="0" DisconnectReason="0">
                                <Bundle SortKey="NO_BUNDLE" BundleId="0" ConnectReason="0" DisconnectReason="0">
                                    <ChargeItem SortKey="ICE">
                                        <SupplementaryOffer OfferId="80000000" ConnectReason="1" DisconnectReason="0" OrderId="23">Fishfingers & Custard
                                            <MonthAmount ProrateCode="0" BillRecur="4" FromDate="2019-07-11" ToDate="2019-08-10" Discount="0.00" Qty="1">4.00</MonthAmount>
                                        </SupplementaryOffer>
                                        <SupplementaryOffer OfferId="80000132" ConnectReason="1" DisconnectReason="0" OrderId="2">A large amount of potato
                                            <MonthAmount ProrateCode="0" BillRecur="71" FromDate="2019-07-11" ToDate="2019-08-10" Discount="0.00" Qty="1">1.00</MonthAmount>
                                        </SupplementaryOffer>
                                    </ChargeItem>
                                    <ChargeItem SortKey="NODSP">
                                        <SupplementaryOffer OfferId="80003606" ConnectReason="1" DisconnectReason="0" OrderId="10">Smaller amount of potato
                                            <DateStart>2016-11-04</DateStart>
                                            <UsageAmount Discount="627.68">630.13</UsageAmount>
                                            <UsageItem>
                                                <ChargeDescr>IncludedSnacks</ChargeDescr>
                                            </UsageItem>
                                            <UsageItem>
                                                <ChargeDescr>SharedSnacks</ChargeDescr>
                                            </UsageItem>
                                        </SupplementaryOffer>
                                        <SupplementaryOffer OfferId="80000132" ConnectReason="1" DisconnectReason="0" OrderId="2">A ginormous amount of potato
                                            <MonthAmount ProrateCode="0" BillRecur="71" FromDate="2019-07-11" ToDate="2019-08-10" Discount="0.00" Qty="1">1.00</MonthAmount>
                                        </SupplementaryOffer>
                                    </ChargeItem>
                                </Bundle>
                            </ParentBundle>
                        </ChargeItemList>
                    </BrilliantProducts>
                </ProductsSection>
            </ServiceAddressCharges>
        </Page2>
    </BILL>
</BATCH >
```

Based on ordering by the 'OrderID' attrib, I would like the outcome of the first 'ChargeItem' to be:

```
<ChargeItem SortKey="ICE">
    <SupplementaryOffer OfferId="80000132" ConnectReason="1" DisconnectReason="0" OrderId="2">A large amount of potato
        <MonthAmount ProrateCode="0" BillRecur="71" FromDate="2019-07-11" ToDate="2019-08-10" Discount="0.00" Qty="1">1.00</MonthAmount>
    </SupplementaryOffer>
    <SupplementaryOffer OfferId="80000000" ConnectReason="1" DisconnectReason="0" OrderId="23">Fishfingers & Custard
        <MonthAmount ProrateCode="0" BillRecur="4" FromDate="2019-07-11" ToDate="2019-08-10" Discount="0.00" Qty="1">4.00</MonthAmount>
    </SupplementaryOffer>
</ChargeItem>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils, req
html = '''
<ChargeItem SortKey="ICE">
    <SupplementaryOffer OfferId="80000000" ConnectReason="1" DisconnectReason="0" OrderId="23">Fishfingers & Custard
        <MonthAmount ProrateCode="0" BillRecur="4" FromDate="2019-07-11" ToDate="2019-08-10" Discount="0.00" Qty="1">4.00</MonthAmount>
    </SupplementaryOffer>
    <SupplementaryOffer OfferId="80000132" ConnectReason="1" DisconnectReason="0" OrderId="2">A large amount of potato
        <MonthAmount ProrateCode="0" BillRecur="71" FromDate="2019-07-11" ToDate="2019-08-10" Discount="0.00" Qty="1">1.00</MonthAmount>
    </SupplementaryOffer>
</ChargeItem>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
ChargeItem = doc.select('ChargeItem@SortKey="ICE"')
SupplementaryOffers = ChargeItem.selects('SupplementaryOffer')
xmls = {} # Cache node and OrderId correspondence
for e in SupplementaryOffers:
    xmls[int(e.OrderId)] = e.outerHtml

Orderids = [int(id) for id in SupplementaryOffers.select('OrderId()')]
Orderids.sort() # Sort OrderId and replace nodes in this order
i = 0
for e in SupplementaryOffers: # Replace nodes in order
    e.repleaceSelf(xmls[Orderids[i]])
    i += 1

print(doc.html) # Output sorted XML
```

Result:

```
<ChargeItem SortKey="ICE">
    <SupplementaryOffer OfferId="80000132" ConnectReason="1" DisconnectReason="0" OrderId="2">A large amount of potato
        <MonthAmount ProrateCode="0" BillRecur="71" FromDate="2019-07-11" ToDate="2019-08-10" Discount="0.00" Qty="1">1.00</MonthAmount>
    </SupplementaryOffer>
    <SupplementaryOffer OfferId="80000000" ConnectReason="1" DisconnectReason="0" OrderId="23">Fishfingers & Custard
        <MonthAmount ProrateCode="0" BillRecur="4" FromDate="2019-07-11" ToDate="2019-08-10" Discount="0.00" Qty="1">4.00</MonthAmount>
    </SupplementaryOffer>
</ChargeItem>
```

Here are more examples, including parsing and updating: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples